# Azure Load Balancer uses zone 1 since subscription xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx does not support zone 1 in location westus

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to create a load balancer in `Azure` using `terraform` but I am getting this error:

> Error: creating/updating Load Balancer "lbclassic" (Resource Group "apim-appGw-RG"): network.LoadBalancersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="SubscriptionDoesNotSupportZone" Message="Cannot create/move resource /subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/apim-appGw-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/lbclassic/frontendIPConfigurations/lbclassic which uses zone 1 since subscription xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx does not support zone 1 in location westus." Details=[]
> │
> │   with azurerm_lb.example,
> │   on 12-lb.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_lb" "example":
> │    1: resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {

And here's my code sample:

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "lbclassic"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "lbclassic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.lb.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. It only fails on West US

I fixed it by adding availability_zone ="No-Zone" under frontend_ip_configuration

```
frontend_ip_configuration {
name                          = "SQLFrontEnd"
#subnet_id                     = var.lb_azure_subnet_id
subnet_id=var.subnetid
private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
private_ip_address            = var.sql_front_end_ip
availability_zone ="No-Zone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure location 'westus' doesn't support availability zones.

See [Azure regions with Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region#azure-regions-with-availability-zones) for the ones that do.